# How security control for DbAdmin activity in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security, logging, monitoring, database-administration

I have a big project and using SQL Server for its database. I'm going to give the database to DbAdmin for restore. But I don't want to know the structure of the database or data for DbAdmin.

One solution is to use encryption but it doesn't have a good performance.

Monitoring is possible to do DbAdmin activity?

Is there a better mechanism to do it?

Is there software to do this?

Comment: IF you have a **DB Admin** that does the restore - he will have direct and full access to your database. Nothing you can do to prevent this, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. How can taking log and monitoring for this activity in some special tables?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you're asking with your comment here. Of course you can audit any activity on your server - but of course, as a DBA, the person operating can turn these audit functions off, too ....

Answer (score 0):

Sysadmin accounts are specific because no security checks are done for their actions, ever. In essence, you cannot stop a sysadmin do whatever she or he pleases in SQL Server.

Only way to secure the data is to encrypt them outside the server, either by using hardware or software methods.

However, if you're running enterprise edition of SQL Server, you can use SQL Server Audit feature to monitor access to the data, both by regular users and sysadmins. Of course, a sysadmin can stop the audit, but you'll at least have the information that it was stopped so you can investigate further.

Just make sure to chose windows security log for the audit destination.